# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Multiple properties named 'ContentType' found in type 'EventData'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am trying update my Azure Function App to V4

I have function within it, which is triggered by the IoT Hub.

When I run my App I am getting following error during run time.

```html
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'iothub_incoming'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Multiple properties named 'ContentType' found in type 'EventData'.
[2022-12-20T17:13:36.456Z] Error indexing method 'iothub_incoming'
[2022-12-20T17:13:36.456Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'iothub_incoming'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Multiple properties named 'ContentType' found in type 'EventData'.
```

Has anyone else experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency between Azure functions core tools and the V4 Azure function App. A similar issue has been reported on Github in the past. Here is the link to the issue -  [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Multiple properties named 'ContentType' found in type 'EventData'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28850)

The ticket mentions that this issue is fixed with new version of azure function core tools v4.0.4544. You can upgrade the core tolls version using the command below

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true
```

Refer the following resource on [Changing Core Tools versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#changing-core-tools-versions)

Here the run book to check different compatibilities and any code changes that may need when you [Migrate apps from Azure Functions version 3.x to version 4.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-isolated%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

If you still face issues with the function after upgrading the tools, you can report the issue in the GitHub link [Azure SDK for .Net issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues)

Comment: Thanks
So I type that once I start my visual studio project and click tools-> command line?
As I have core 4 installed, but it seems its version 4.0.3928 , .

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.3928 Commit hash: 7d1d4a32700695bbf290a871c7492fde84bb767e  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.0.1.16815

So how do I update that?

Comment: Try running the following in your project root directory to get the latest version--
 npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.4915 --unsafe-perm true

Alternatively, you can also try and see if you can find the package under the project dependencies --> packages from Visual Studio solution explorer and update it by right clicking the package and choosing update. Note that if you used Windows installer (MSI) to install Core Tools on Windows, you should uninstall the old version from Add Remove Programs before installing a different version.

Comment: Yes, i have uninstalled it, but it seems to still be somewhere on my PC.  I will try that command. 



I have another function app project, which is still on version 3, which I do not want to change at this stage, so I still need core 3 for that version.

Comment: I have types npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.4915 --unsafe-perm true, by clicking Tools --> command line -->Developer PowerShell, bt its still refering to the older version,

Comment: Looks like there are still remnants of old version on your system. Try uninstalling from the control panel through uninstall a program option. Instead of trying to install the core tools through npm command, try with the windows 64-bit installer which can be accessed from the following resource [Install the Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

Comment: There was Function core tool installed, which I uninstalled. But seems it does not make any difference as both this project and Version 3 project are still able to compile

Comment: Does Visual Studio, have any option of manually setting the core in your project? As it seems I can use the both recent version of 4.

Comment: If you are on Visual Studio 2022 edition, you can create a package.json file for the list of dependencies and explicitly mention the package dependency version. Please refer the resource, [Add npm support to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2022#npmAdd) for more information

Comment: Ok, i will try it, but if I want to see the version of core tools installed in my project how can I do that and also how can I change it as well? I think I got global version 4 installed somewhere and when I preform an update my project does not use it.